# The clock used in boost's wait_for is not exactly

Tags: c++, boost, unique, future

I am using boost library as shown in the code below.
I want to exit after 60 seconds, but the result takes 62.369 seconds. What's wrong?

```
bool istimeout = false;
boost::chrono::milliseconds span(60 * 1000);
int cnt = 0;


high_resolution_clock::time_point start = high_resolution_clock::now();

boost::unique_future<void> executegetaction = boost::async(boost::launch::async,
[&]() {
    while (!istimeout) {
        Sleep(10);
    }
});

boost::future_status futurestatus = boost::future_status::ready;
futurestatus = executegetaction.wait_for(span);

high_resolution_clock::time_point end = high_resolution_clock::now();
double checktime = (duration<double>(end - start)).count();

std::cout << checktime << endl;

if ((bool)futurestatus)
{
    istimeout = true;
}
```

> 62.369

Comment: The OS you are using is not a realtime OS and any waits will be subject to the OS scheduler waking up the thread.

Comment: However, the wait_for of std gives 60.0151 result. The margin of error is much smaller.

Answer (score 0):

The C-style cast `(bool)` invites UB. So is the data race on `istimeout`. Don't.

Besides, let me compare

### Boost

[Live On Coliru¹](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4258ab3ba065b708)

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using C = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using boost::chrono::seconds;

int main()
{
    using boost::this_thread::sleep_for;

    boost::atomic_bool istimeout(false);

    auto action = boost::async(boost::launch::async, [&]() {
        while (!istimeout) sleep_for(seconds(10));
    });

    auto start = C::now();

    boost::future_status futurestatus = action.wait_for(seconds(60));

    using boost::chrono::duration;
    std::cout << (C::now() - start) / duration<double>(1.0) << std::endl;

    istimeout = futurestatus != boost::future_status::ready;
}
```

Prints 60.0001 (or 6.00022 [on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4258ab3ba065b708))

On my machine.

### Standard

[Live On Coliru¹](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d408245537ac4980)

```
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main()
{
    auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now;
    using std::this_thread::sleep_for;

    std::atomic_bool istimeout(false);

    auto action = std::async(std::launch::async, [&]() {
        while (!istimeout) sleep_for(10s);
    });

    auto start = now();

    std::future_status futurestatus = action.wait_for(60s);

    std::cout << (now()-start)/1.0s << std::endl;

    istimeout = futurestatus != std::future_status::ready;
}
```

Prints 60.0001 (or 6.00029 [on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d408245537ac4980))

### Conclusion

There's no conclusion. Thread scheduling is not deterministic. System load, kernel tuning, it all comes into play. If you get consistent weirdness, check with the exact listings I provided (I moved some things around to prevent e.g. measuring starting of threads, which may be especially slow on your system?).

If it still manifests, start by listing versions (compiler, libraries) flags (linker and compiler) and the target machine specs (arch, CPU, kernel version/configs, memory, load etc.).

Comment: Added Live Demos on Coliru but ¹ scaled down 10x to allow them to complete: [Boost 6.00022s](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4258ab3ba065b708) vs. [Standard 6.00029s](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d408245537ac4980)

Comment: The longer the time, the larger the error. So, when it is 60 seconds, the error is bigger.
I know it is affected by the system specs, but the problem is that there is a clear difference between Standard and Boost. FYI, VisualStudio2019 (v142) fixed this issue. But I need to use VisualStudio2017(v141).

Comment: Did you even see my answer? I compared the snippets on my machine with 60s. No measurable difference. Finally, if this is a known issue (fixed in v142) why didn't you mention it in the question? Really, that's all there is to say. A bit of time wasted.